# How can I build Qt 5.13.2 with GCC 11.1 on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, build, qt5

I have been building Qt 5 for a long time successfully on Windows using GCC/MinGW-w64. When I try the same with GCC 11.1, the build fails with a strange error message. What can I do to make it work?

I have built the compiler myself using the `develop` branch of https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds with this command:

```
../build --mode=gcc-11.1.0 --arch=x86_64 --buildroot=/c/mingw-builds/BuildRoot --update-sources --exceptions=seh --threads=posix --enable-languages=c++ --jobs=48 --rt-version=v7
```

Then I retrieve Qt like this on an MSYS2 console:

```
# Ensure that the right Perl is being used to prevent the possible later compilation error "fatal error: QVector: No such file or directory"
export PATH=/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/:$PATH

cd /c
cd Libraries/
mkdir Qt
cd Qt
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
git checkout v5.13.2
perl init-repository --module-subset=essential --berlin
cd ..
```

Then I try to build Qt:

```
mkdir Build
cd Build
../qt5/configure -prefix ../Install -release -recheck-all -confirm-license -opensource -platform win32-g++ -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtsensors -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwinextras -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine
mingw32-make -j 48
```

But `configure` displays a lot of errors similar to this:

```
qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qendian.h:333:35: error: 'numeric_limits' is not a member of 'std'
```

How can I fix it?

Additionally I would like to link it against the "FreeType" library (version built for MinGW) that is distributed by "Open CASCADE" (see https://dev.opencascade.org/resources/download/3rd-party-components). How is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues to solve.

First I have to patch Qt, since with GCC 11 some header dependencies have changed and Qt 5.13.2 does not always include the right headers (see https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/porting_to.html or [How Can I Include Header Files by Compilation Flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67773119/how-can-i-include-header-files-by-compilation-flags)).

Therefore I add the line

```
#include <limits>
```

within the `#ifdef __cplusplus` block
to the file

```
qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h
```

If no own FreeType libary is used, the build succeeds now.

But when I add the `configure` command options

```
-system-freetype -I /c/Libraries/OpenCascade/3rdPartyMingw64/freetype-2.6.3-mingw-64/include -L/c/Libraries/OpenCascade/3rdPartyMingw64/freetype-2.6.3-mingw-64/bin -L/c/Libraries/OpenCascade/3rdPartyMingw64/freetype-2.6.3-mingw-64/lib
```

and then run `mingw32-make -j 48`, I get the following error message:

```
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx:  Attempt to access invalid address.
```

This can be solved by adding the option `-no-pch` to the `configure` command. The call now looks like this:

```
../qt5/configure -prefix ../Install -release -recheck-all -confirm-license -no-pch -opensource -platform win32-g++ -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests -system-freetype -I /c/Libraries/OpenCascade/3rdPartyMingw64/freetype-2.6.3-mingw-64/include -L/c/Libraries/OpenCascade/3rdPartyMingw64/freetype-2.6.3-mingw-64/bin -L/c/Libraries/OpenCascade/3rdPartyMingw64/freetype-2.6.3-mingw-64/lib -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtsensors -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwinextras -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine
```

After running `configure` the build can be run with

```
mingw32-make -j 48
```

and it succeeds.

Comment: `-j 48`?! What monster is that, Threadripper?

Comment: @Mikolasan An ordinary Intel CPU. I have never seen disadvantages in building with many threads. :-)

Comment: Thank you. An example patch is in https://gist.github.com/nbenitez/6d13b1a58dc23ed967b943620efcf08a